# Unable to start Parity node

Tags: parity

```
Parity Ethereum version: version Parity-Ethereum/v2.0.1-beta-e7dc0be-20180726/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.27.2
Operating system: Linux
Installation: built from source
Fully synchronized:
Network:
Restarted: yes
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial.html) to set up a private chain with PoA . When i try command parity --config node0.toml.

> Method 1. Using RPC
>       Start the node 0 using parity --config node0.toml.

i get this

```
root@amal:~# parity --config node0.toml 
Loading config file from node0.toml 
Option '--dapps-port' has been removed and is no longer supported. 
2018-08-31 19:33:23 UTC Starting Parity-Ethereum/v2.0.1-beta-e7dc0be-20180726/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.27.2 
2018-08-31 19:33:23 UTC Keys path /tmp/parity0/keys/DemoPoA 
2018-08-31 19:33:23 UTC DB path /tmp/parity0/chains/DemoPoA/db/d0678730db7ea493 
2018-08-31 19:33:23 UTC State DB configuration: fast 
2018-08-31 19:33:23 UTC Operating mode: active 
Consensus signer account not found for the current chain. You can create an account via RPC, UI orparity account new --chain demo-spec.json --keys-path /tmp/parity0/keys`.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you set an address as an "engine_signer" before that you create it.